# Cognos Framework loop resolving

Tags: loops, model, frameworks, relationship, cognos

Please help.
I need to ged rid of loop in Cognos Framework.
I need to choose TPS_EMPLOYEE.WWID and need to be sure that both branches will work at the same time.
From TPS_SALES I need all row and add to them ***WWID*** and ***SECTOR*** columns where **both** branches (SECTORS + CUSTOMERS_EMPLOYEES) conditions are meet.

Before there was no Alias and relationship goes on shortest way (not both). Then I added Alias and now only one branch conditions work.

Can't add image as I have not enough reputation, then I try to make scheme

**TPS_SALES** 1..n <--> 0..1 TPS_MARA 1..1  <--> 0..1 TPS_SECTORS (***SECTOR***)1..1 <--> 0..1 Alias to TPS_EMPLOYEES

**TPS_SALES** (same as on top) 1..n <--> 0..1 TPS_CUSTOMERS_EMPLOYEES 1..1 <--> 0..1 TPS_EMPLOYEES (***WWID***)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is redesign.
Your model is too complex. Create usual star schema and everything will be fine.
Create and load dimension tables in your DWH.

```
TPS_MARA 1..1 <--> 0..1 TPS_SECTORS (SECTOR)1..1 <--> 0..1 TPS_EMPLOYEES
```

and

```
TPS_CUSTOMERS_EMPLOYEES 1..1 <--> 0..1 TPS_EMPLOYEES (WWID)
```

Than join them to your fact table.

Comment: well, you example is like mine - same two branches ended with one TPS_EMPLOYEE (in brackets there is just required field, not the different table name) that cause loop. I have the same and TPS_SALES is the fact table. Well, I made VIEW (TPS_SALES + TPS_MARA + TPS_SECTORS + TPS_EMPLOYEES_CUSTOMERS) in DB and connected TPS_EMPLOYEE in FM. But I really wanted to know how to made all of this directly in FM, if it possible (I don't want to create extra objects in DB).